# how to input array into array of a function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, math

Lets say i have a symbolic function of `array[2 2]`. Each element represents a function. Then i converted it with `matlabFunction()` function into function handler. It is all okay up to now. I can get `2x2` answer matrix for example when i input `f(1,1)`. How can i input an vector instead of putting manually `1 and 1`. For example i want to define `x0=[1 1]` and then put `f(x0)`. Each time i get `Not enough input arguments.` It tries to put `1 to x` and then again `1 to x` and give to answers. But because there is one more variable called y it gives not enough input argument error. Any suggestion? Basically i want to create f(x), where f and x are matrices. So it becomes system of equation.

For example:

```
variable1= [1 1]

 jac= @(a,b)reshape([b,a.*2.0+a.^2.*b.^2.*3.0,a+b.*2.0,a.^3.*b.*2.0],[2,2])
 jac(variable[1 1])
Not enough input arguments.

Error in symengine>@(a,b)reshape([b,a.*2.0+a.^2.*b.^2.*3.0,a+b.*2.0,a.^3.*b.*2.0],[2,2])
```

but when

```
jac(1,1)

ans =

     1     3
     5     2
```

Comment: Please include that symbolic function and your code in your post

Comment: @SardarUsama Done

Comment: Just copy this variable1= [1 1]

 jac= @(a,b)reshape([b,a.*2.0+a.^2.*b.^2.*3.0,a+b.*2.0,a.^3.*b.*2.0],[2,2])
 jac(variable[1 1])   and it will work. After put jac(1,1) to recreate my problem, i also edited the question you can copy from there also

Comment: Thanks let me check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your function with one variable instead of two. i.e.

```
jac = @(x) reshape([x(2), x(1).*2.0+x(1).^2.*x(2).^2.*3.0, ...
   x(1)+x(2).*2.0, x(1).^3.*x(2).*2.0], [2,2]);
```

Now you can give it input as `jac(variable1)` which, as expected, returns:

```
ans =

     1     3
     5     2

% where variable1 = [1 1]
```

but since you get that anonymous function as a result of applying [`matlabFunction()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/matlabfunction.html), so you need to make the respective changes in your making of symbolic function i.e.  use `syms x` instead of `syms a b` and replace `a` with `x(1)` and `b` with `x(2)` in your code.

Comment: But this function comes from the matlab, i did not define it. It is a long code that is why i gave a part of it. But everything should be automated. Is there a way that i make matlab define existed function as one variable as you suggested?

Comment: Because the code takes derivative of input function, there has to be different variable names to get its jacobian function?

Comment: @ssovukluk as you wrote you converted your function using `matlabFunction`, if you show the function that you had before conversion, it can be possible to define it in terms of one variable

Comment: @ssovukluk You can fix that by using `syms x` instead of `syms a b` and replacing `a` with `x(1)` and `b` with `x(2)` in your code. If you do that, I am very positive that your problem will be fixed

Comment: still the same result

Comment: check it again. I can't really think of anything without seeing the code you're using

Comment: I made a code which writes code :D it writes its own jac(1,1) etc and includes into code. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @ssovukluk Seems like an interesting AI. Good luck with your work!